# How do I pass form data over a websocket? (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

```
<form name="input" action="">
    <input type="text" name="say" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

I want to send the data in this form to the server via web sockets, i'm using socket.io.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why websocket here? This is a client-server request, so normal http request would work.

Comment: If the form changes the state on the server then it would be nice to be able to emit those changes to clients without needing the clients to long poll the server. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd need to use [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form like so:

```
var formdata = $('form').serialize();
```

Then pass that over the websocket. On the node.js side, you can get a JS object back by using [querystring.parse](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/querystring.html#querystring.parse):

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
// Data is the data received from the client
var result = querystring.parse(data);
```

Answer (score -3):

**you can try this**

```
    function getFormData2Object(form){
    var un_array = form.serializeArray();
    var _array = {};
    $.map(un_array, function(n, i){
        if(n.name.indexOf('[') > -1 ){
            var array = n.name.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
            var key = n.name.replace(array[1],"").replace('[',"").replace(']',"");
            if(!_array[key]){
                _array[key] = {};
            }
            _array[key][array[1]] = n['value'];
        }else{
            _array[n['name']] = n['value'];
        }
    });
    return _array;
}
socket.emit('blablabla', getFormData2Object( $("form") ) );
```

good luck :)

Comment: Add some explanation with your code, it can help others in the future. [answer]